# Accesing a single pixels alpha in an UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I'm trying to make that detects for collision ignoring transparent area.  I have all of it done but a function that returns wether or not a single pixel in a UIImageView is transparent or not.  Currently putting together some posts from here I have:

```
- (BOOL)IsPixelNonTransparentFromImage:(UIImage*)image atX:(int)x andY:(int)y {
    CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
    NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    unsigned char *rawData = (unsigned char*) calloc(height * width * 4, sizeof(unsigned char));
    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height,
                                             bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                             kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    NSUInteger byteIndex = (bytesPerRow * y) + x * bytesPerPixel;
    CGFloat alpha = (rawData[byteIndex + 3] * 1.0)/255.0;
    free(rawData);
    return alpha > 0.0;
}
```

Not only does this not work for me but also I'm pretty sure there is a more sleek solution for just finding one pixel.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is code that should detect alpha of a single pixel:

```
- (BOOL)IsPixelNonTransparentFromImage:(UIImage*)image atX:(int)x andY:(int)y {
    unsigned char pixel[1] = { 0 };
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixel, 1, 1, 8, 1, NULL, (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaOnly);
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
    [image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(-x, -y)];
    UIGraphicsPopContext();
    CGContextRelease(context);
    return pixel[0] != 0;
}
```

The idea is to draw the image into a context that is one pixel by one pixel at the offset of `(-x, -y)`, so that the point at `(x, y)` gets "drawn" into the single pixel of the bitmap context that we create. This avoids dynamic allocation and rendering the whole picture to speed up the processing. `kCGImageAlphaOnly` is used to capture only the alpha channel of the picture.

Here is a program to test this code:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BlueCircle.png"];
NSLog(@"%@", [NSValue valueWithCGSize:image.size]);
for (int y = 0 ; y < image.size.height ; y++) {
    NSMutableString *buf = [NSMutableString string];
    for (int x = 0 ; x < image.size.width ; x++) {
        [buf appendFormat:@"%c", [self IsPixelNonTransparentFromImage:image atX:x andY:y] ? '*' : '-'];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", buf);
}
```

Here is a [link to the `BlueCircle.png` image that I used for testing](http://s15.postimg.org/nppqftfg7/Blue_Circle.png).

When this code runs, I get this printout in the log:

```
2015-04-15 20:15:55.213[10456:620425] ---------************---------
2015-04-15 20:15:55.213[10456:620425] -------****************-------
2015-04-15 20:15:55.214[10456:620425] ------******************------
2015-04-15 20:15:55.214[10456:620425] ----**********************----
2015-04-15 20:15:55.215[10456:620425] ---************************---
2015-04-15 20:15:55.216[10456:620425] ---************************---
2015-04-15 20:15:55.216[10456:620425] --**************************--
2015-04-15 20:15:55.217[10456:620425] -****************************-
2015-04-15 20:15:55.217[10456:620425] -****************************-
2015-04-15 20:15:55.218[10456:620425] ******************************
2015-04-15 20:15:55.219[10456:620425] ******************************
2015-04-15 20:15:55.219[10456:620425] ******************************
2015-04-15 20:15:55.220[10456:620425] ******************************
2015-04-15 20:15:55.278[10456:620425] ******************************
2015-04-15 20:15:55.279[10456:620425] ******************************
2015-04-15 20:15:55.279[10456:620425] ******************************
2015-04-15 20:15:55.280[10456:620425] ******************************
2015-04-15 20:15:55.280[10456:620425] ******************************
2015-04-15 20:15:55.281[10456:620425] ******************************
2015-04-15 20:15:55.281[10456:620425] ******************************
2015-04-15 20:15:55.282[10456:620425] ******************************
2015-04-15 20:15:55.282[10456:620425] -****************************-
2015-04-15 20:15:55.283[10456:620425] -****************************-
2015-04-15 20:15:55.283[10456:620425] --**************************--
2015-04-15 20:15:55.284[10456:620425] ---************************---
2015-04-15 20:15:55.284[10456:620425] ---************************---
2015-04-15 20:15:55.330[10456:620425] ----**********************----
2015-04-15 20:15:55.331[10456:620425] ------******************------
2015-04-15 20:15:55.331[10456:620425] -------****************-------
2015-04-15 20:15:55.332[10456:620425] ---------************---------
```

Comment: I tested your solution by placing an image of a blue circle 30 pixels by 30 pixels(the outside of the ball is transparent) and with some for loops I tested every point ((0-30),(0-30)) and all returned false! Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @user3143098 I am not sure what this could be, but I get a perfect circle printed out when I test this. I added a link to my image, the testing code, and the output that I got running it.

Comment: Just got it to work.  The thing is when I was plugging in x and y values i thought it was regular pixels but apparently it is not.  I thought image dimensions and frame dimensions are the same but they're not, for example my frame is 30 wide but my image is 186 wide.  Is this how its supposed to be?  Because of this I was getting all false because I was testing 0-30! Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user3143098 Right, `x` and `y` are in the image's coordinates, not in its containing frame coordinates. Scaling the image is also possible if you call `CGContextScaleCTM` before "drawing" the image.